# Center align background-image of an input button

Tags: jquery, css

This might sound like a simple fix, but let me explain it in detail.

I've an `<input type="submit"/>` button and I'm trying to align the arrow to the right of the button text (which is already center aligned).

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6rrzsa4/4/
[image: submit button]

Now coming to the issues:

1. I cannot change the `<input>` to a `<button>` tag since it comes
   from a CMS).
2. The button text can be anything, which means I cannot crop the arrow
   image with an offset(equal to the width of the text) and use
   background-position:center.
3. I cannot add :after pseudo element for the parent div, since it
   makes the arrow area unclickable.
4. As I already said the button text can change. So I cannot use percentages for background-position.
5. The button has a fixed width (sorry, forgot to add this point).

Comment: Of course you can change the input to a button, using jQuery it's rather simple.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you posted on jsfiddle?

Comment: can you just put `>` sign at the end of text?

Comment: @odedta It really depends tho—if there are other events bound to the input element (but not to the form submission event), then the DOM replacement method would not work :( but that's also a tell-tale sign of bad design.

Comment: @Terry, it's quite simple to check if other events are hooked to that `input` element.

Comment: I have used icon code using FA.. If you want like that then here is the http://jsfiddle.net/GrBJF/119/

Comment: You could use CSS `calc()`, e.g: `background-position: calc(100% - 30px);` http://jsfiddle.net/2pv4ba5x/  See calc() support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc  Keeping `right` in background declaration to handle older browsers support.

Comment: Can you create a div before that input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@felix solution is good. But it has downside of appending span element to body, in order to calculate width of the text. We can use canvas to calculate the width of the text yet it won't be append to DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/s6rrzsa4/16/

```
var elem = $('input'),
    cs = window.getComputedStyle(elem[0]),
    context =  document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    metrics, pos;

    context.font = cs.fontSize + " " + cs.fontFamily;

    metrics = context.measureText(elem[0].value.toUpperCase()), 
    pos =  (elem.width() - metrics.width)/2 + 20;

    elem.css('background-position','calc(100% - '+pos+'px) center');
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, The only issue now, is with firefox and that's fixed when the 'background-position-x','calc(100% - '+pos+'px)' is replaced with 'background-position','calc(100% - '+pos+'px) center' ;

Answer (score 4):

For finding the text length, used a dummy `span` and used some javascript to calculate the `background-position-x`.

```
var a = $("input").outerWidth();

var s = $('<span class="dummy" />').html($("input").attr('value'));

s.appendTo('body');

var b = s.outerWidth();

var pos = b + (a-b)/2;

$("input").css({
    'background-position': pos +'px center'
});

s.remove();
```

Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/s6rrzsa4/9/

Comment: The best solution so far... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1)you can use :after pseudo with style `pointer-events: none;`
but its not supported in IE http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

2)put `>` sign at the end of string

Comment: But he said *"I cannot add :after pseudo element for the parent div, since it makes the arrow area unclickable."* which means he wants that to be click-able right?

Comment: I believe you can't even add :after pseudo-elements to `input` elements.

Comment: @light `I cannot add :after pseudo element for the parent` *div* i dont know how his structure looks like, but if clickable area is a problem, im saying - it is not

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're pretty limited in your choice of "nice" solutions.

The easiest way I can think to do this in your situation is to get a list of every text possibility your button value can be and target the CSS with the value:

```
div input[value="Anything"] {
    background-position: 200px 30px;
}
```

Here's your updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6rrzsa4/8/